# Digram list manipulation with Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, optimization

I'd like to make additions/replacements to the digram list which looks similar to this:

```
[[a,b][b,c][c,d][d,c][c,b][b,a]]
```

If the list is flattened, outcome would be: ´´[a,b,c,d,c,b,a]´´ but this is just for describing the structure, not the issue.

> Note that there are only two items on a digram and each of the two items on a 
>   digram precedes the next and the previous digram items, except of the first
>   and the last digram, where terminating item occurs only once. See item
>   ´´a´´.

My question is that how can you replace digrams to the list, so that next example results on the comment part would fulfill:

```
replace([['d','d']],          1, ['a', 0]) # should return: [['d', 'd']]
replace([['d',1]],            1, ['a', 0]) # should return: [['d', 'a'], ['a', 0]]
replace([[1,'d']],            1, ['a', 0]) # should return: [['a', 0], [0, 'd']]
replace([[1,'d'],['d', 1]],   1, ['a', 0]) # should return: [['a', 0], [0, 'd'], ['d', 'a'], ['a', 0]]
replace([['d',1],[1,'d']],    1, ['a', 0]) # should return: [['d','a'], ['a', 0], [0, 'd']]
replace([[1,1]],              1, ['a', 0]) # should return: [['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0]]
replace([[1,1],[1,1]],        1, ['a', 0]) # should return: [['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0]]
```

I have tried the next approach, but it has some issues. Especially the part under ´´j == 1´´ has special cases that doesnt work.

```
def replace(t, a, b):
    """
    1. argument is the target list
    2. argument is the index value to be used on replacement
    3. argument is the digram to be inserted
    """
    # copy possibly not needed, im not sure
    t1 = t[:]
    for i, x in enumerate(t1):
        for j, y in enumerate(x):
            # if there is a digram match, lets make replacement / addition
            if y == a:
                if j == 0:
                    c = t1[i:]
                    del t1[i:]
                    t1 += [b] + c
                    c[0][0] = b[1]
                if j == 1:
                    c = t1[i:]
                    del t1[i:]
                    t1 += c + [b]
                    c[len(c)-1][1] = b[0]
                    #c[0][1] = b[0]
                    #t1 += c

    print (t, t1)
```

Can you suggest some tips to improve the function or have alternative ways to do the task?

### Addition

This is my enchanged version of the function, which provides right answers, but still "annoying" part of it or whole approach could be optimized. This question and topic could be changed more to the code optimization area:

```
def replace(t, a, b):
    """
    1. argument is the target list
    2. argument is the index value to be used on replacement
    3. argument is the digram to be inserted
    """
    l = len(t)
    i = 0
    while i < l:
        for j, y in enumerate(t[i]):
            # if there is a digram match, lets make replacement / addition
            if y == a:
                if j == 0:
                    c = t[i:]
                    del t[i:]
                    t += [b] + c
                    c[0][0] = b[1]
                    # increase both index and length
                    # this practically jumps over the inserted digram to the next one
                    i += 1
                    l += 1
                elif j == 1:
                    c = t[i:]
                    del t[i:]
                    # this is the annoying part of the algorithm...
                    if len(c) > 1 and c[1][0] == a:
                        t += c
                    else:
                        t += c + [b]
                        c[-1][1] = b[0]
                    t[i][1] = b[0]
        i += 1

    return t
```

I also provide test function to test inputs and outputs:

```
def test(ins, outs):
    try:
        assert ins == outs
        return (True, 'was', outs)
    except:
        return (False, 'was', ins, 'should be', outs)

for i, result in enumerate(
    [result for result in [
[replace([['d','d']],          1, ['a', 0]), [['d', 'd']]],
[replace([['d',1]],            1, ['a', 0]), [['d', 'a'], ['a', 0]]],
[replace([[1,'d']],            1, ['a', 0]), [['a', 0], [0, 'd']]],
[replace([[1,'d'],['d', 1]],   1, ['a', 0]), [['a', 0], [0, 'd'], ['d', 'a'], ['a', 0]]],
[replace([['d',1],[1,'d']],    1, ['a', 0]), [['d','a'], ['a', 0], [0, 'd']]],
[replace([[1,1]],              1, ['a', 0]), [['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0]]],
[replace([[1,1],[1,1]],        1, ['a', 0]), [['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0]]],
[replace([['d',1],[1,1]],      1, ['a', 0]), [['d', 'a'], ['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0]]],
[replace([[1,1],[1,'d']],      1, ['a', 0]), [['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0], [0, 'd']]]
]]):
    print (i+1, test(*result))
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, an example with some explanation would help.

Comment: I would recommend not *actually* storing a bigram list as a list of bigrams, but rather as a list of words, and write functions that access them as bigrams. You're literally doubling your space requirements for nothing here.

Comment: @L3viathan You are correct, I'm doubling the space, but in doing so, I'm decreasing the need of processing power on the other part of the module. There is always a balance between memory consumption and processing power you need to take in account. Also in cases, when you are not creator of the components you are using, you have to deal with data structure you are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my approach.  Explanation below.

```
def replace(t, a, b):
    # Flatten the list
    t = [elem for sub in t for elem in sub]
    replaced = []
    # Iterate the elements of the flattened list
    # Let the elements that do not match a in and replace the ones that
    # do not match with the elements of b
    for elem in t:
        if elem == a:  # this element matches, replace with b
            replaced.extend(b)
        else:          # this element does not, add it
            replaced.append(elem) 
    # break up the replaced, flattened list with groups of 2 elements
    return [replaced[x:x+2] for x in range(len(replaced)-1)]
```

You start with some list of lists.  So first, we can flatten that.

```
[[1,'d'],['d', 1]] becomes [1,'d','d', 1]
```

Now we can loop through the flattened list and anywhere we find a match on `a` we can extend our `replaced` list with the contents of `b`.  If the element does not match `a` we simply append it to replaced.  We end up with:

```
['a', 0, 'd', 'd', 'a', 0]
```

Now we want to take all of these in groups of 2, moving our index 1 at a time.

```
[['a', 0] ...]
[['a', 0], [0, 'd'], ...]
[['a', 0], [0, 'd'], ['d', 'd'], ...]
```

If your data was substantially longer than your examples and was in need of performance improvements, the flattening of the list could be removed and you could flatten the value in `t` with a nested loop so you would make a single pass through `t`.

**EDIT**

```
def replace(t, a, b):
    t = [elem for sub in t for elem in sub]

    inner_a_matches_removed = []
    for i, elem in enumerate(t):
        if not i % 2 or elem != a:
            inner_a_matches_removed.append(elem)
            continue
        if i < len(t) - 1 and t[i+1] == a:
            continue
        inner_a_matches_removed.append(elem)

    replaced = []
    for elem in inner_a_matches_removed:
        if elem == a:
            replaced.extend(b)
        else:
            replaced.append(elem)
    return [replaced[x:x+2] for x in range(len(replaced)-1)]
```

And here is an addition for testing:

```
args_groups = [
        ([['d','d']],          1, ['a', 0]),
        ([['d',1]],            1, ['a', 0]),
        ([[1,'d']],            1, ['a', 0]),
        ([[1,'d'],['d', 1]],   1, ['a', 0]),
        ([['d',1],[1,'d']],    1, ['a', 0]),
        ([[1,1]],              1, ['a', 0]),
        ([[1,1],[1,1]],        1, ['a', 0]),
]

for args in args_groups:
    print "replace({}) => {}".format(", ".join(map(str, args)), replace(*args))
```

Which outputs:

```
replace([['d', 'd']],             1,   ['a', 0]) => [['d', 'd']]
replace([['d', 1]],               1,   ['a', 0]) => [['d', 'a'], ['a', 0]]
replace([[1, 'd']],               1,   ['a', 0]) => [['a', 0], [0, 'd']]
replace([[1, 'd'], ['d', 1]],     1,   ['a', 0]) => [['a', 0], [0, 'd'], ['d', 'd'], ['d', 'a'], ['a', 0]]
replace([['d', 1], [1, 'd']],     1,   ['a', 0]) => [['d', 'a'], ['a', 0], [0, 'd']]
replace([[1, 1]],                 1,   ['a', 0]) => [['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0]]
replace([[1, 1], [1, 1]],         1,   ['a', 0]) => [['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0]]
```

I guess I still don't understand case #4, but you seem to have solved it yourself which is Great!

Here is your modified code:

```
def replace(t, a, b):
    # Flatten the list
    t1 = []
    l = len(t)-1
    for items in [t[i][0:(1 if i>-1 and i<l else 2)] for i in range(0,l+1)]:
        t1.extend(items)
    replaced = []
    # Iterate the elements of the flattened list
    # Let the elements that do not match a in and replace the ones that
    # do not match with the elements of b
    for elem in t1:
        if elem == a:  # this element matches, replace with b
            replaced.extend(b)
        else:          # this element does not, add it
            replaced.append(elem) 
    # break up the replaced, flattened list with groups of 2 elements
    return [replaced[x:x+2] for x in range(len(replaced)-1)]
```

Comment: Good one, but 5. should return: [['d','a'], ['a', 0], [0, 'd']] and 7. should return: [['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0], [0, 'a'], ['a', 0]]

Comment: @MarkokraM Does it not?  Pretty sure I tested every input / output.  And I don't see why those would be treated any differently based on the algorithm.  Not at a computer now or I would reverify

Comment: @MarkokraM I see that the output you have and what my function returns are in fact different for #5 and #7.  I do not, however, see what the special case is with those two.  Is there some other case you have not described or I did not pick up on?

Comment: So in [['d',1],[1,'d']] number 1 in the middle is actually "interpreted" as single 1. This means that replacing it with some digram should produce replacee only once. If replacee is ['a', 0] then output should be:  [['d','a'],['a', 0],[0,'d']]. If you would like to flatten it to the underlying sequence, it would be ['d', 'a', 0 'd']. Can you make any sense of this?

Comment: In other words construction of t in the beginning of your function needs to have a bit more complex logic.

Comment: Still example 4 gives wrong output. I made a change to the same part. Now code seems to yield correct outputs and perform a bit better. See if you can accept that change animplement on your code: https://repl.it/BlBb/0 Then I'm ready to accept the answer.

Comment: Done and done.  Well done on solving the rest yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Your version is also faster than while loop I made, so I'm satisfied with it now. Answer accepted.